# Is it possible to change a pseudo element's text using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have a nav menu with li elements,the lists are styled as

```
li:after { content : "+" }
```

Is it possible to change the content from  **"+" to  "-"**  when user clicks on the li , using jquery?

Comment: No, you will need to have the character inside the li instead. `li.text("+");` will alter to plus. `li.text("'");` to minus.

Comment: thanks Andes for your help .. but i can't put text direct in the li bcoz there already menu name :(

Comment: You can have a li like this: `var li = $("<li><span class='menuname'/><span class='sign'/></li>");`, then you use `li.find('.menuname').text("themenu"); li.find(".sign').text("+");`. Of if it is declared in html, it will look like `<li><span class="menuname"></span><span class="sign"></span><li>`